# clearInterval function is not working with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What's wrong with this code?

The `setInterval()` does not stop. it´s a infinity looping.

Here is the code of the view.

```
var chat = require('core/chat');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
var agentOfferTemplate = require('hbs!templates/agent-offer');
var contador = 20;
var intervalID;

AgentOfferView = Backbone.View.extend({


    template : agentOfferTemplate,


    initialize : function() {
        this.timeAccept();
    }, 


    render : function() {
            this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

    timeAccept : function(){ 
        if (contador > 0){
            $('#tempo').html(contador); 
            $('#barra-interna').css('width', contador * 10);
            intervalID = setInterval(this.timeAccept, 1000);                
            contador = contador - 1;
        }
        else {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            intervalID = null;
            $('#countdown-container').hide();
    contador = 20;                 
        }
    }

});

 return AgentOfferView;
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called using either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, the `this` keyword looses its reference (the function is invoked in a new context). `this` will, generally speaking, reference either `null` (in strict mode) or the global object.
Read the section entitled [*The "this" problem*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) on MDN for more details. Basically, you're passing a reference to a function to `window.setInterval`, which calls that function in the context of the `setInterval` function, which is obviously `window`... Since the global object clearly doesn't have a `timeAccept` method, your timout loop runs but once, not 20 times. It's as simple as that.
The quickest way around the issue IMO is to use a closure, and pass the entire context to the interval function:
It is, thankfully, an easy fix:

```
    timeAccept : function()
    { 
        if (contador > 0)
        {
            $('#tempo').html(contador);
            $('#barra-interna').css('width', contador * 10);
            intervalID = setTimeout((function(context)
            {//pass current this reference to closure
                return function()
                {//instead of this, use context
                        setInterval(context.timeAccept, 1000);
                };
            }(this)),1000);
            contador--;
        }
        else
        {
            clearTimeout(intervalID);
            intervalID = null;
            $('#countdown-container').hide();
            contador = 20;                 
    }
```

An interval is something that calls a given function over and over again, each X milliseconds.  Looking at your code, you'd probably want to use `setTimout`, which calls the function only once.
As it now stands, you're creating 20 intervals, each calling the same function every second. Even if `contador >= 0`, the intervals keep on calling the function.

Consider the folowing examples:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function()
{
    console.log('You\'ll see this appear every second');
    console.log('This interval has an ID, and it\'s: ' + intervalId);
},1000);

var timeout = setTimeout(function()
{
    console.log('This will only appear once, after 1000ms');
    console.log('A timeout has an ID, too: ' + timeout);
},1000);

//using the ID's you can cancel both the timeout and the interval using these lines:
clearInterval(intervalId);
clearTimeout(timeout);//usefull if you want to cancel the delayed function call...
```

Comment: I had already tried the timeout, but the method is only called once.

it stops at 19.

Comment: @alex: try clearing prior to setting a timeout/interval. initialize the ID var to `0`, and take things from there...

Comment: I'm noob in the backbone. This must be the problem. I debugged the code and found that using the timeout, the timeAccept method is not called.

Comment: @alex: I've edited my answer because I was wrong: the true issue here is that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` don't play nice when the keyword `this` is being used. I've added a quick-fix suggestion and a link to the MDN with some more details.

Comment: Elias, thank you very much for the help. With your implementation the timeout get out of sync.

Comment: @alex: looking at your profile, it might prove useful to learn about voting/accepting answers. If you ask a question, you can vote on answers regardless of how much rep. you have. check this link on hoe to accept: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and this one on how to vote: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
timeAccept : function(){ 
        var intervalId = setInterval(
            function(){
                if (contador > 0){
                    $('#tempo').html(contador); 
                    $('#barra-interna').css('width', contador * 10);
                    contador--;
                }else{
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    $('#countdown-container').hide();
                    contador = 20;
                }
            }, 1000);
    }
```

This way works fine.